# How to solve the Name Conflict Error occured in MSAccess 2007 Reports (VB6)

Tags: vb6

I have a MSAccess2003 DB in which few reports are present(Reports are in VB 6.0 Code),i migrated from 2003 to 2007 using the option in 2007,now few of the files which i referred in the 2003 version are not present in the 2007 version(repository),and if i add a reference to a component which is refereed in 2003 it gives an error like "Name conflicts with existing modules,projects or object library" . Can anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check the link Below which will solve this error

http://kalidadiz.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/access-2007-recordset2/

**Edit:** Info in the link...

> But when I tried to compile it, the declaration I just made is
>   highlighted when this compile error message appeared:

User-defined type not defined

> As it turned out, the Recordset2 object needed the
>   support of an object library named Microsoft Office 12.0 Access
>   Database Engine Object Library. Thinking that I quickly found the
>   solution, I went right ahead and added this library via the
>   Tools-References within the VBA Editor… and this error showed up:

Name conflicts with existing module, project or object library

> I guess it
>   wasn’t that quick to solve after all! Next step I had to do was figure
>   out how to get rid of this second error, and internet to the rescue
>   once more! As it turned out, the conflict had something to do with an
>   existing library that’s already in the references section.  The
>   conflicting libraries are: Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library Microsoft
>   Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Object Library The first is an
>   already existing library in the references, and does not seem to allow
>   the second one to be added, and thus, well, the conflict. I found an
>   explanation for this online: the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library is
>   useful only if you work with the .mdb format, and although this still
>   works with the new .accdb format, a much better choice is the
>   Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Object Library, which
>   handles everything that the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library does, as
>   well as provide support for the new 2007 version. Armed with this
>   explanation, I removed the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library from the
>   References, and then added the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database
>   Engine Object Library… Problem solved!